# Why did East Germany fail? And why did DDR need hard currency 1986-1989?

Tags: political-history, germany, german-unification

Sometime back I saw [Deutschland 83](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4445154/) then [Deutschland 86](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6148324/) and finally [Deutschland 89](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8760304/). The sad part is even though you see the series, you don't really understand why did East Germany fail? Why exactly did East Germany go bankrupt, what went wrong? This is never explained in either of the three mini-series. How much Moscow was responsible for it or any part of it, not known.

The only answer remotely about the whole situation seems to be this [question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/45329/was-the-berlin-wall-breached-based-upon-an-erroneous-declaration/45333#45333) but it is an entirely different question altogether. Looking to know more, thank you.

There is also no explanation provided why the East German Mark failed. I looked at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_currency), and hard currency seems to be something like the Euro or the US Dollar or maybe even the Chinese remnibi as they are now pegging their currencies to a basket of currencies and allowing it to fall or rise within a certain range in that.

While it is fascinating to know about those turbulent times, it seems one is left with an incomplete picture of what happened and why?

There is a quote by one of the actors in (I think 1986/1989 series) in which she implies that Soviet stopped funding East Germany but doesn't give any figures as to how much they had been funding per year to give some idea. There is also a [documentary](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13399664/) which sheds some light as to how East Germany tried to make a shortfall but that also doesn't get into the question as to why East Germany failed.

Comment: Did the Deutsche mark fail as in the D-Mark or do you mean the DDM ie DDR's mark ?   One reason for the trouble in Poland in 1980 were the loans in foreign currency intended  to pay for investments in the coal and steel industry - but the world  crisis in the steel industry became even worse due to the over supply.

Comment: @StefanSkoglund In the mini-series it is implied that the currency used in east germany failed. To be more precise, I was looking at the East German mark https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_German_mark.

Comment: @LаngLаngС, I have edited question just a tiny bit so that opinionated answers are less, but I would welcome more edit by you, if you think you could make the question more objective. At least in the mini-series, it is implied that economic issues started appearing in and around 1986 but doesn't tell why. There is nothing which explains why they were unable to balance the books. The solutions are shared, but why things came to such a pass, that part is missing.

Comment: I can't speak to your TV series, but Eastern Europe in general wasn't all that happy with Communism.  Once the USSR under Gorbatchev indicated that it would fight to keep control over its satellites, things quickly spiraled out of control in 1989.  The exact economics of the Soviet bloc were always murky in any case with both overestimations of Soviet output by the CIA and overvaluations of their currencies when you compared official vs black market rates.  And "balancing the books" has a vastly different meaning in a command economy than it does in the West.  Or even China.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica could you explain or link to something which explains how it was different than what is done in West or even China. I do know that the popular image of communism is that people were dumb, they would just make estimates of how much number of things based on number of people rather than taking into account people's choices, weather etc. As somebody who quoted in the documentary I shared above, communism would have worked if not for four factors, and he shares the four seasons. 1/n

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica the implication of the above sentence thinks that communism failed to understand the dynamism of people and the market place. People's need change overtime and this is something that communism was unable to either comprehend or didn't know. I have no clue whether that is right or even the inference I drew from the statement above is right or not. The economics just muddies the water more rather than make things clear.

Comment: China currently is using normal currency and accounting, albeit in a totalitarian state.  But in true Communist economies, 5 year plans decide who produces what and who gets what.  A tractor factory doesnt get *paid* for its tractors, it *produces* them.  But it also doesn't *buy* the *steel* to make them, it *gets* it.  (This is also another reason for Communism' failure:  all this shuffling around of resources has to be *planned*, can't self-organize).  As a result, money, and accounting, work differently, unless they are used to in foreign commerce.  Hard to compare apples and oranges.

Comment: I come from India and we similarly had the 5 yr. planning thing. We also had a balance of payments problems in 1991. Whether it was due to USSR breaking down or not is unknown, although it is pretty big coincidence. Hence having some idea of the Germany at that time and then what happened in USSR may also tell part of our story, don't know.

Comment: I don't know the series you are mentionning, but explaining the collapse of the Eastern block, in particular East Germany (which was the "model-state" among the Eastern block), mainly by a currency issue looks to me an opinion, not more. The reasons are so many and so intricated... a little like climate changes: slow, imperceptible, underground evolution, then acceleration, then a situation that becomes unmanageable...

Comment: Upvote - this is a deceptively good question.  This is asking us to clarify underlying assumptions that make studying the economic history of the period very difficult. Definition of "hard currency" in command and free economies and similar concepts need to be clearly expressed.  Good question.

Comment: @shirish: The problem is not that planned economies don't understand about people's needs & desires, and how they change, it's that they have no good way of measuring them.  That's because any way of actually measuring is effectively creating a market.

Comment: @shirish - Please don't respond in comments; that is an anti-pattern.  Everything that OP knows or believes should be edited into the question. Longer comment strings are associated with lower quality questions.

Comment: If the DDR wanted goods from the West, they needed hard currency or setting up a barter exchange (like Pepsi and old Soviet navy ships in the 70's).

Comment: Currencies in the Socialist countries were, by design, **internal currencies** ([Binnenwährung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binnenw%C3%A4hrung)). Prices did not necessarily reflect the actual cost of the product. As such, therefore, they didn't fail for their **intended purpose**.

Comment: "outcompeted" might be a more accurate term. Those countries didn't exist in a vacuum. They were certainly more successful than third-world countries, but definitively less successful than their western neighbors.

Answer (score 4):

(Putting this as answer, because while not extremely detailed and scarcely sourced - which would be hard to do effectively - this was an event I was following at the time, living in Europe).

I can't speak to your TV series, but Eastern Europe in general wasn't all that happy with Communism. Once the USSR under Gorbachev indicated that it would not fight to keep control over its satellites, things quickly spiraled out of control in 1989.

The exact economics of the Soviet bloc were always murky in any case with both overestimations of Soviet output by the CIA and overvaluations of their currencies when you compared official vs black market rates.

"Balancing the books" has a vastly different meaning in a command economy than it does in the West. Or even China `*`.

(note:  the paragraph below is deliberately a bit provocative.  Is it 100% correct?  80%?  60%?  But it is **not** 100% incorrect either, a Communist state does not have a buy/sell market in the sense we normally understand it, is a [centralized command economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planned_economy#Central_planning).  How much did this apply to the DDR vs USSR?  Hard to say as well, but the DDR was still operating under a Communist government ultimately subservient to Moscow).

In true Communist economies, 5 year plans decide who produces what and who gets what. A tractor factory doesn't get *paid* for its tractors, it *produces* them. But it also doesn't *buy* the steel to make them, it *gets it allocated*. This is also another reason for Communism's failure: all this shuffling around of resources has to be planned, it can't self-organize, and it requires *unrealistically* competent top-government management, something that is often absent in Western systems too.

Some links:

https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/economics/staff/mharrison/public/jce2011postprint.pdf

https://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/stalinmodel.htm

As a result, money, and accounting`*`, work differently, unless they are used to engage in foreign commerce.  Local money, depending on how doctrinal the system was, might be used mostly by individuals to purchase minor luxuries.  Foreign suppliers of needed goods/technology would demand payment in hard currency, or, failing that, would insist on barter arrangements.

In such a context, as a black market develops and shortages generalize, the official currency rate means less, and only hard foreign currency is trusted.  Indeed, in some cases, some regimes run foreigner-only, dollar-only stores to soak up hard currency.

Communist governments had chronic shortages of hard currency and some Western companies had set themselves up as [barter facilitators](https://www.contradealer.co.uk/pepsi-and-the-soviet-union-an-unusual-case-of-business-bartering/) to benefit from the situation.

Also at the same time, the Economist was writing that some Soviet activities were *subtracting* value. I.e. a Lada might objectively be expected to sell for less in a free market than the value of its inputs such as steel, energy and labor.  [Trabants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trabant) were off the roads within a few years of the collapse; they would have made a good investment for collectors.

Cuba was also the target of big Soviet wealth transfers, with, for example, oil, for the same reasons:  showcasing Communist successes to the world.  They suffered greatly, after the USSR collapsed, when those stopped.

So it would be very hard to reason in detail on what caused economic hardships for East Germany, *besides the very nature of its economic governance under Communism*.  Books could certainly be written on forensic economic analysis of Communist systems.

`*` China currently is using normal currency and accounting, albeit in a totalitarian state.

`**` post-East Block collapse, The Economist would run articles bemusedly explaining how Western business consultants would struggle to explain the very notion of accounting to factory managers who had never thought in its terms.  The implication wasn't that they were stupid, only that this was just not something they had been tasked with looking after.

Comment: I believe there is a "not" missing in your second paragraph.

Comment: Do you have a source for your assertion that enterprises in Eastern European countries did not receive money when giving their products to other enterprises?

Comment: Tangential, but see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_goods_in_the_Soviet_Union  Group A is what I am talking about - those work by allocation, not purchasing.  Also, see https://spartacus-educational.com/RUSfive.htm and the notion of *procurement quotas*, for the farmers.  This  is not grain they *sell*, it's grain they have to *give*.

Comment: http://www.industriemuseum-schoenebeck.de/seite31.htm claims that VEB Fortschritt, East Germany's producer of tractors, had 1.2 billion DDR-Mark in sales in the 1980s. This seems quite a lot if they were unable to sell to companies (and East German agriculture was quite fully collectivized)

Comment: Some things that were tried out in the Soviet Union before WWII may not have been repeated in post-WWII East Germany.

Comment: Good point.  see also https://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/stalinmodel.htm  Keep in mind, Communism is a touchy subject and, without vetting, I am might easily quote unreliable sources.  But on the whole, Communist economies did **not** operate on a profit/loss, buy/sell system as we think of them nowadays.  One of Deng Xiaopeng early reforms in China was to let farmers sell *some* of their harvest.  Whether that was as true in the DDR as the USSR I do not know, but I do know that applying Western economic metrics to Eastern bloc countries is hard to do.

Comment: Btw. that spartacus link does not really say that the peasants got *nothing* for their quota, does it? Only that selling stuff privately was more profitable.

Comment: and the ssju link mentions enterprise *profits*, but also goes on to say *The logic of the system is that the higher authorities **gave** the enterprise the labor and material resources and it is up to the enterprise manager to get as much production from those resources as possible.*

Comment: I don't think there is anything touchy about the statement "A tractor factory doesn't get paid for its tractors [..] But it also doesn't buy the steel to make them[...]" when it comes to East Germany in the 1980s. It is either true or not, or we don't know. If it is not true or we do not know, it should not be in your answer. Given that East Germany had "Industrieabgabepreis" and stuff like that, I personally would assume that the statement is not true.

Comment: @Jan by touchy I mean that a lot of citations about Communism are going to be ludicrously false misinformation.  "In true Communist economies" doesn't mean "DDR in 1980", only that comparisons need to be put into context. I'll tweak this answer later, but my general point stands:  reasoning about 1980 DDR in 2020, from a capitalist POV, is not as simple as it might seem.